# How to extract a coastline of the lake for fractal analysis

Tags: imagej, fractals

I am new to ImageJ software. I want to extract the boundary of the lake which I am analyzing. I am outlining the method that I saw in a article. The author says:

" As an example we take the Noanamakki Reservoir whose image is shown in Fig. 1. We first extract the boundary of the lake one is analyzing. In order to achieve this, the water body is first colored black and then the binary image consisting only the water body is extracted (Fig. 2).Then the edge detection algorithm is used to obtain the boundary of the lake as depicted in Fig. 3"

I wonder how I achieve the above method using ImageJ.

- Fig1:
  [image: jpeg image of the lake]
- Fig2:
  [image: Black colored water body]
- Fig3:
  [image: The edge of the lake for the fractal analysis]

Comment: There is little sense in trying without the original high quality data. Low resolution and lossy compressed data won't lead to reasonable results. Furthermore, the described processing appears being sub-optimum. Initially filling the selection is in fact unnecessary.

Comment: @Herbie, I am using Google Earth Pro pictures. Do you advice any other method?

Comment: You need much better resolution and less compression artifacts. Here <https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/images/150249/lake-powell-still-shrinking> you'll find a better example but still JPG-compressed however, showing less artifacts. It is rather easy to get a reasonable contour by first using the magic wand tool with adequate tolerance. Then create an empty image of the same size, restore the selection and draw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help to apply the magic wand tool to an image that results from a colour space transformation. I tried it with the 8bit b*-channel after Lab-transformation. Setting the wand tool to Legacy, and using a tolerance of about 30 works quite well. However, some lake regions may need retouching. Here are the binary images of "Lake Powell" (with the "Glen Canyon"-dam at the bottom) that correspond to the images you've shown:
[image]
[image]
The original image is from the link posted in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to calculate the length and fractal dimension of the boundary between land and water, you could try using the Marching Squares algorithm. It provides you with data about said boundary.